# How do I check if other arrays contain the value I want to add before using $addToSet in mongodb/mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to check if other 'sets' have the value I want to add. If another set has the value, then remove it from that set and add it to the new set.`{
    "_id": "5a052785aa06c22429717bad",
    "word": "wordtest5",
    "__v": 0,
    "pronunciations": [
        {
            "pronunciation": "wordtest1",
            "_id": "5a052785aa06c22429717bae",
            "likes": [
                "remove_this",
                "5a0508cfcf4f6620786a3cb1"
            ],
            "rating": 1
        },
        {
            "pronunciation": "wordtest5",
            "_id": "5a0674c1053ae929db3a576c",
            "likes": [],
            "rating": 1
        },
        {
            "pronunciation": "testing5",
            "_id": "5a06770346be3d2ac6f31561",
            "likes": [
                "remove_this",
                "5a0508cfcf4f6620786a3cb1",
            ],
            "rating": 1
        }
    ]
}`

I want to remove all 'remove_this' string inside every 'likes' array.

Answer (score 0):

Use **$pull** on other 'sets' you mention and use **$addToSet** on the actual set you want to add. This way you can achieve what you want.

Next time please be very clear on your question.

Comment: Hi, I posted an example and tried     `Word.findOneAndUpdate({ word }, { $pull: { 'pronunciations': { 'likes' : userId } }}, {multi : true})` but couldn't get it to remove the element.